# How to get posts from wall as facebook feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

I have a problem with Facebook. Let me explain what I'm trying to do. My friend granted me access to his fanpage as administrator. I would like to get all feeds from fanpage's wall, by using php script on my website. How can I do that ? I don't have any app id or secret id, because this is not an app - it's fanpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily retrieve posts from `feed` connection [of `page`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) (use `posts` connection if you only want posts Page own).

You'll need an application to do so because both `posts` and `feed` connection require **any valid `access_token`** for access.

Once you have `access_token` you may simple retrieve the posts with Graph API:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed?access_token=...
```

Comment: how can I generate the access_token for that fanpage ?

Comment: You doesn't really need an [`access_token` for Page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/) (this require user `access_token` and `manage_pages` permission), just **any valid** one. Actually the easies and simplest is create application and use [application `access_token`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/) (even old format `APP_ID|APP_SECRET` will work)